# Installing Origin and/or Steam games automatically in an unattended manner

Tags: steam, origin

Does anyone know of a way of installing Steam and/or Origin games automatically, without user intervention?

I have a very unusual set up where I use an AWS instance for gaming. At the moment I have all the games installed manually but the problem is that I need to keep a relatively large storage volume around and that alone costs about half of what I'd pay for the actual computing power (snapshots don't solve this problem because the IO performance on a freshly restored one is disastrous).

The idea would be to only keep a very small volume with the OS, Origin, Steam and a bunch of utilities, and download the games automatically at boot onto an ephemeral volume which gets destroyed when the instance is shut down. The bandwidth is high enough that it doesn't take more than 10 minutes to download the few games I care about, so that delay would be more than acceptable.

Does anyone have any ideas where to start?

Comment: you can store your actual games folders in S3 or Glacier

Comment: I have to ask, why are you using an AWS instance for gaming? I can't imagine any scenario (pre-coffee) where lag (input or graphics) wouldn't factor into your game play experience. Turn based games would probably be exempt from that, but it seems like an unnecessary cost to play games.

Comment: @arghtype I already do that (via snapshots which are stored on S3), the performance is a disaster. Also, Origin (at least, haven't checked Steam) seems to host the game files on AWS and bandwidth within AWS is free, so it would be cheaper to just redownload them on every run rather than paying to store copies myself.

Comment: @Sorean due to my job I am required to move often and on short notice, so I don't want to invest in a good gaming rig (also I have little time so the rig wouldn't be used enough to justify the investment, where as on AWS I just pay per hour). Playing on AWS with a good internet connection (through Steam Remote Play) is surprisingly viable, even for competitive multiplayer shooters.

Comment: I'm curious as to what kind of instance you are using for this.

Comment: @Sorean I am using a `g4dn.xlarge` instance which is enough to run Battlefield 3 on max graphics. You might want to use a bigger instance if you’re playing a newer game.

Comment: Any chance [this self-answered question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/296805/203077) helps? It's another user on AWS who used the commandline to automate Steam game installation after the instance was started.

Answer (score 2):

### Steam

Valve provides CLI : https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD

So it's possible to install games like this:

```
steamcmd +login anonymous +force_install_dir ../csgo_ds +app_update 740 +quit
```

Which logins to steam, creates custom folder and then installs CS:GO there.

This tool supports both Linux/MacOS and Windows, so you should be good automating your setup with it.

One limitation though, looks like it doesn't work for all the Steam games:

> It works with games that use the SteamPipe content system.

### Origin

I cannot find anything working right now, but in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/179419/144891) author invested some time into Origin API.